# How to create a column in a pandas data frame depending of other columns of it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame and I want to add a column to it depending on other columns.

Here is the code I have :

```
report["newColumntoCreate"] = report["aColumn"].astype("str") + "-" + report["anotherOne"].astype("str")
```

Is there a faster way to do it? Or better way to write it? If the line is too long, how can I make it get checked by the PEP8 requirements?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752087/pandas-how-to-create-a-column-based-on-values-of-another-column

Comment: Break the line with a `\\`, keep going on the next one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
report['newColumntoCreate'] = report[['aColumn', 'anotherOne']].astype(str).apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it:

```
report['newColumntoCreate'] = report['aColumn'].astype(str).str.cat(report['anotherOne'].astype(str), sep='-')
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems virtually impossible to do this more quickly, but at least you can make it on two lines.

```py
report["newColumntoCreate"] = report["aColumn"].astype("str") \
                      + "-" + report["anotherOne"].astype("str")
```