# Python create new dataframe column based on different rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So I am having dataframe which looks like this

```
       v1   v2
day1   x    x
day2   x    x
day3   x    x
day4   x    x
day5   x    x
```

What I need is to add new column v3 which will be the difference "today's v1 - yesterday's v2"

I've tried `df[v3] = df[v1][1:] - df[v2][:-1]`

But it looks like python is somehow mapping rows by timestamp and I am receiving "today's v1 - today's v2" as result except for first and last rows which are NaN.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752087/pandas-how-to-create-a-column-based-on-values-of-another-column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, as your days monotonic increasing, you may subtract `v1` by `v2.shift()`

```
df['v3'] = df.v1 - df.v2.shift()
```